Why does the blend of many cicadas sound lower-pitched than individual nearby ones?
In the last emergence of Brood XIX, I noticed that the nearby cicadas made individual chittering sounds that you could hear against a more distant background of a warbling "flying saucer" sound. The flying saucer sound was fairly high pitched (around the C# an octave above middle C), but the individual cicada sounds weren't the same pitch - they seemed to mainly have a higher pitch but with lots of white noise.
Obviously, the more distant sound was the combined sound of all the chittering noises, but I'm curious if anyone has done an analysis of how the lower-pitched ambient sound is derived from the higher-pitched chittering sounds.
My guess is that the higher frequencies somehow dissipate more or are filtered out by the trees, but I would be really curious to know if someone has worked this out in detail. I realize this may be more of a physics question than a biology question, but I thought I would start here.
(Another reason I find it interesting is that I don't notice the same sonic phenomenon when the dog day cicadas come out every year later in the summer. I just hear the chittering sounds.)
